# SED: Search and replace two expressions with backslash

Tags: bash, sed, replace, latex, backslash

I am attempting to search and replace a string using `sed`. Both the search and replace strings have backslashes in them. For example

```
var="\text{kpll}"
var2="k_{\parallel}"

sed -i.bak "s|$var|$var2|g" MathematicaToLaTex.tex
```

This does not work as expected. I was expecting to have

```
\text{kpll} ---> k_{\parallel}
```

Instead, I am getting

```
\text{kpll} ---> \k_{parallel}
```

It seems that `sed` is correctly finding the string `\text{kpll}` just fine, but it is not replacing it accurately. Have looked through the forums but could not find a solution. Have tried changing delimiters, using `'` instead of `"`, but to no avail. Have also tried changing the file type from `.tex` to `.txt`, but made no difference. Running this in Terminal in MacOS.

------- Edit -------

I required **both** changing the single backslash to a double, and changing the variable name quotes from `"` to `'` for it to work.

Comment: Did you try escaping the backslash, i.e. `var2="k_{\\parallel}"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the backslash and replace `"` with `'`:

```
var='\\text{kpll}'
var2='k_{\\parallel}'
sed -i.bak "s|$var|$var2|g" MathematicaToLaTex.tex
```

Comment: Perfect --- it was the combination of the ` \\ ` and `" --> '` that did it. Why does one need the `'`? It did not work without it.

Comment: If you use `"` bash removes one backslash. If you want to use `"` replace your backslash with three backslashes.